# Приходит не правильный ip если тестировать клиент на Genymotion

Tags: java, android, сокет, virtualbox, genymotion

Я получаю неправильный ip c клиента на Android если тестировать программу на Genymotion:

```
byte[] replyBuffer = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(replyBuffer, replyBuffer.length);
socket.receive(reply);
DebugCl().mLog("ip="+reply.getAddress().getHostName())//вывод в логи
```

Если тестировать программу на реальном устройстве, ip правильный все хорошо. 
Я так понял так и должно быть? Может можно что то сделать, ведь надо протестировать программу на многих версиях android, ну кроме конечно просто заменить ip в ручную на правильный, для теста.

Comment: Genymotion - работает за счет виртуалки VirtualBox, IP будет неправильный - здесь все в порядке.

Answer (score 2):

Genymotion работает в VirtualBox. VirtualBox немного мудрит с IP-адресами, поэтому нужно настраивать локальный IP адрес вручную, как, например, тут - [ссылка](http://coding4streetcred.com/blog/post/VirtualBox-Configuring-Static-IPs-for-VMs).